# Progress bar of some files do not load (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this is my problem.

I have an input to upload several files at the same time, then I have an ajax that is responsible for sending the request and events listener to load the bars.

The problem is when I upload 8 files and some do not meet the validations (size and format), then draw most of the bars and the last ones do not.

The file is uploaded but neither the bar nor the text is drawn

[image: Upload screen]

This is the javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var newFileList = [];
    $('.addfiles').on('click', function () { $('#fileUploader').click(); return false; });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
            if (this.files.length != 0) { $("#btnUpload").attr('disabled', false); };
            $("#bars").remove();
            $("#divFiles").append('<div id="bars"></div>')
            for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) { //Progress bar and status label's for each file genarate dynamically
                var fileId = i;
                const file = this.files[i];
                if (validateFileExtension(file)) {
                    $("#bars").append(
                        '<div id = "' + fileId + '" >' +
                        '<div>' + file.name + '</div>' +
                        '<div class="progress">' +
                        '<div class="bar" id="progressbar_' + fileId + '" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>' +
                        ' </div>' +
                        '<div>' +
                        '<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="display:none;line-height:6px;height:25px" id="cancel_' + fileId + '" value="cancel">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div>' +
                        '<p class="progress-status" style="text-align: right;margin-right:-15px;font-weight:bold;color:saddlebrown" id="status_' + fileId + '"></p>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div>' +
                        '<p id="notify_' + fileId + '" style="text-align: right;"></p>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>'
                    );
                }
            };
            $('file_count').text('# Files selected: ' + newFileList.length);


        })
    });
    function uploadFiles() {
        var file = document.getElementById("fileUploader")//All files
        for (var i = 0; i < newFileList.length; i++) {
            uploadSingleFile(newFileList[i], i);
        }
    }
    function uploadSingleFile(file, i) {
        var fileId = i;
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //Progress Listener
        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
            console.log(file);
            var percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
            $("#status_" + fileId).text(Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded, please wait...");
            $('#progressbar_' + fileId).css("width", percent + "%")
            $("#notify_" + fileId).text("Uploaded " + (e.loaded) + " KB of " + (e.total) + " KB ");
        }, false);
        //Load Listener
        ajax.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
            $("#status_" + fileId).text("File upload!");
            $('#progressbar_' + fileId).css("width", "100%")

            //Hide cancel button
            var _cancel = $('#cancel_' + fileId);
            _cancel.hide();
        }, false);
        //Error Listener
        ajax.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
            $("#status_" + fileId).text("Upload Failed");
        }, false);
        //Abort Listener
        ajax.addEventListener("abort", function (e) {
            $("#status_" + fileId).text("Upload Aborted");
        }, false);

        var imagePath = window.location.search;
        var filePath = imagePath.replace("imagePath", "filePath");
        ajax.open("POST", "/File"+filePath); // Your API .net, php

        var uploaderForm = new FormData(); // Create new FormData
        uploaderForm.append("file", file); // append the next file for upload
        ajax.send(uploaderForm);

        //Cancel button
        var _cancel = $('#cancel_' + fileId);
        _cancel.show();

        _cancel.on('click', function () {
            ajax.abort();
        })
    }

    function validateFileExtension(file) {

            if (!/(\.bmp|\.jpg|\.gif|\.png)$/i.test(file.name)) {
                bootbox.alert("Invalid file type:" + file.name + " . Only JPG, GIF, PNG or BMP File");
                return false;
            }       
        // Validate Size
        var imgsize = document.getElementById('ImgSize').value;
            var size = file.size;
            // check file size
            if (size > imgsize) {
                $(this).val("");
                bootbox.alert("The size of  " + file.name + "  is too big:  " + size + " Byte, you only can upload " + imgsize + " Byte");
                return false;
        }
        newFileList.push(file);
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

---

EDIT

apply the changes but follow the same problem the file is uploaded, but the bar is not drawn on the screen or anything else

```
function uploadFiles() {
     filesToUpload = newFileList.slice(0);

     uploadSingleFile(filesToUpload.pop(), 0); // start the process here
}
function uploadSingleFile(file, i) {
    var fileId = i;
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //Progress Listener
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
        var percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        $("#status_" + fileId).text(Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded, please wait...");
        $('#progressbar_' + fileId).css("width", percent + "%")
        $("#notify_" + fileId).text("Uploaded " + (e.loaded) + " KB of " + (e.total) + " KB ");
    }, false);
    //Load Listener
    ajax.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
        $("#status_" + fileId).text("File upload!");
        $('#progressbar_' + fileId).css("width", "100%")

        //Hide cancel button
        var _cancel = $('#cancel_' + fileId);
        _cancel.hide();
    }, false);
    //Error Listener
    ajax.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
        $("#status_" + fileId).text("Upload Failed");
    }, false);
    //Abort Listener
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", function (e) {
        $("#status_" + fileId).text("Upload Aborted");
    }, false);

    var imagePath = window.location.search;
    var filePath = imagePath.replace("imagePath", "filePath");
    ajax.open("POST", "/File" + filePath); // Your API .net, php

    var uploaderForm = new FormData(); // Create new FormData
    uploaderForm.append("file", file); // append the next file for upload
    ajax.send(uploaderForm);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
            if (ajax.status === 200) {
                console.log('successful');
                if (filesToUpload.length > 0) { // do this inside your ajax success call
                    uploadSingleFile(filesToUpload.pop(), ++i);                      
                }
                else {
                    console.log(ajax.status);
                    console.log('failed');
                }
            }
        }
    }

        //Cancel button
        var _cancel = $('#cancel_' + fileId);
        _cancel.show();

        _cancel.on('click', function () {
            ajax.abort();
        })

}
```

Comment: why are you calling  uploadSingleFile(newFileList[i], i); in a for loop? Your file upload operation is asynchronous. the best way to do is to do one upload and on completing the first one do next. You also need to understand that there are domain level restrictions from browsers, so you can have only 6 connections open at a time in a browser (example: 6 in Chrome)

Comment: call that function in a loop because the controller in the backend waits for a single file, as I should do so that just after finishing one, start the next one?

Comment: Yes exactly. In this way you will not run into domain level restrictions in the network layer. But if you want to have multiple connections open then you need to write a logic to process this in batches. Like 3 connections 1st batch and 3 conenctions in the 2nd batch. This also means you need to rewrite your backend code to effectively manage these type of connections. The multiple connections is just my opinion. It involves a lot of changes and if you architecture permits that.

Comment: and what would be the javascript way to wait for an upload to finish and then start the next one?

for the moment I could not contemplate the scenario of the multiple connections, since it is a fast implementation.